# I want to set negative numbers in a view to zero and any positive should remain the same

Tags: sql, case

```
select field1, field2, Field3,
case when exists
(select field1
from tbl1
where field < 0) then 0 else field1 end as Field2
from tbl1
```

Comment: What database engine do you use?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming its T-SQL, its similar to a question from earlier but here goes:

```
SELECT [your fields here] ,
CASE WHEN [COLUMN_NAME] <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE [COLUMN_NAME]  END AS [NEW_COL_NAME]
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: Though obviously you'll want a column alias on the `CASE` and probably a list of fields instead of `*`

Comment: Further to @Daniel's comment on `*` you could take a look at my question on Meta [Are some bad practices within answers acceptable? Specifically SELECT *](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91558/are-some-bad-practices-within-answers-acceptable-specifically-select)

Comment: An excellent point, will make use of that clause in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Use this snippet in the query you create the view from:

```
IF(field < 0, 0, field)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is MySQL syntax you wrote here, don't know if it is applicable to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT field1, 
    field2, 
    Field3, 
    CASE 
        WHEN  field < 0  THEN 0 
        ELSE field1 
    END as Field2 
    FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like follow-

```
select 
case
when field1<0 then 0
else field1
end as field1
from tbl
```